# Can I run electrical raceway on a baseboard?

Tags: electrical

I have a Panduit ldp5 I'd like to mount on a baseboard.  As you can see from the photos, the path above the baseboard is blocked by an existing outlet and further down, by a radiator.  The box fits nicely on the baseboard and the raceway blends.  The only downside I can think of is that the outlets will be low and perhaps more prone to being kicked or scraped by furniture.

The raceway is for 120V electrical outlets.
 [image: Baseboard where raceway would be run]  [image: Outlet box]

Comment: What's going in this raceway?

Comment: I updated the question, this is for electrical.  The product is rated for electrical.  I went with plastic over metal raceway because the latter is apparently very difficult to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is fine

Article 388 sets out the usage conditions for non-metallic surface raceways such as yours, and I seriously doubt that being at a baseboard is going to subject your raceway to the "severe physical damage" mentioned in 388.12 point 2.  Considering that it's an exposed application, indoors where temperatures are presumably benign, your raceway is UL listed for power service (to 600V no less), and not subject to any other significant restrictions from Article 388 (definitely not hazard classified or in an elevator hoistway!), you are good to go running 120V power wires through this raceway setup.  One note though: you will want to run individual stranded THHN wires for hot, neutral, and ground in the raceway instead of a NM cable -- NM doesn't go around your average raceway elbow well at all.

Comment: the manufacturer claims wire fill counts that seem a little high given the cross sectional square inches they also state. So I would be careful there.  The cross section certainly precludes any use of NM!  Anyway, given OP's preference for materials that are easy to work with, I would suggest *stranded* THHN. Do not use in backstabs.

Comment: @Harper thanks for the reco on stranded THHN.

Comment: @Harper you were right about the manufacturer's fill counts... way high!  Should be about half of what they state, though I am using RW90 not THHN (the latter does not seem to be available in Canada).  The RW might be thicker.